# is it possible to use Waze offline or for development using their routing algorithm?

Tags: waze

Is it possible to use Waze in an offline or development type mode?

I would like to report things to the Waze system like road closures and have it recalculate my route. I would like to do this many time in an attempt to determine which roads are the most critical in terms of affecting drive times.

Is this sort of thing possible?

What I am looking for is the use of the Waze routing server as a black box in a private manner.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be outside the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: stackoverflow had the most waze tags, did not know where else to ask it, and the question is related to a specific software / algorithm and if something is possible using said software / algorithm, though it is rather general

Comment: Unless I'm misinterpreting, what you appear to be asking about is the use of an end-user tool that has nothing to do with software development, which likely leverages hundreds of distinct algorithms. In any case, I would posit that Google would never allow for use in such a manner; doing so would threaten their trade secrets and competitive advantage by more easily enabling  reverse engineering of said algorithms.

Comment: that is basically my thought but wondering if anyone knows different, but the idea is really to use their end-user tool, but just not publish the closure reports

Comment: for anyone interested, there are open source alternatives such as Graphhopper which do have similar functionality, though I don't believe that you can add road closures/hazard rerouting (yet)